# Paste special (json to a class) missing VS2019 - with all web dev tools installed

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

A very valuable tool is the ability to quickly grab json and create a class.  Paste Special in previous versions of VS was a great feature, but I can't locate it in Visual Studio 2019.

According to [this forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4dccf2b7-af71-4e17-9ba4-cdc4ea9ba0c3/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-missing-quotedit-paste-special-paste-json-as-classesquot?forum=vssetup), you just need to add the ASP web development tools. I've installed everything, paste special nowhere to be found.

How/where do I go to enable this or what is the new alternative provided in Visual Studio 2019?

I've combed through all the options & individual components in Visual Studio Installer, and I've enabled just about everything where this might live. But it's still not showing up in menu.

Comment: I did find this little website that can quickly generate the class properly (I tested this)  http://json2csharp.com/  , but sure would be nice to get the Paste Special back in VS.

Comment: Thank you @RSA answer below, I was in debugging while trying to paste special and only had the XML option.  After stopping debugging, the Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes appeared.

Answer (score 27):

I met the same problems in here too with 2019 visual studio and found out how to fix it.

Go to Visual Studio Installer > Modify > Individual Components > Web development Tools

[image: installer screenshot]

Comment: Worked for me! I think MS should do a better job of communicating this.

Comment: For novices like me https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-paste-json-as-classes-or-xml-as-classes-in-visual-stu/

Comment: This option is now out of support. Does anyone have another approach?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, @Jason

Comment: After insuring that you've got the right components installed, be sure that you have a C# or VB file open for editing. The Paste Special option will only appear if this is the case.

Answer (score 10):

It should be under the Edit menu:

[image: Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes]

If you've installed the ASP.NET tools and still don't see this, [send feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) so the product team can investigate why.

Comment: I'm using VS2019 Enterprise (16.4.5) and it's not there either. It was there before i removed and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't do it often, just use an online [JSON to class converter](https://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Just curious, why do you state "don't do it often"? Any problem with using this on a regular basis? Thank you.

Comment: There's more steps to opening a website, copying, pasting , copying, pasting than there is to just copy & paste directly to code within VS. A lot of people prefer not to have to go outside VS for things that should be built-in. My answer took that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

The "Paste JSON as Classes" option doesn't display when in debug.  Just in case you had the option, but it seemed to disappear.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31084838)

Comment: Interesting that "Paste XML as Classes" DOES appear in the Edit > Paste Special menu - hence why I didn't think of it.  Thanks.

Comment: This did provide an answer for me.  Thanks @RSA

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer. My Paste special disappeared after altering some extensions. I updated Web Essentials 2019 and then uninstalled CodeMaid. When the option disappeared, I tried restarting Visual Studio and it didnt work, but after I restarted my machine, the option came back