# How to Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have this Json String and i have been trying to deserilize it, tried the below:

```
string jsonS = @"{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "network": {
    "id": "ZA-CS2SPT1AJ9ESP"
  },
  "request": {
    "id": "7b4addca-3bb3-4cc6-adb8-e42114867cab"
  },
  "data": {
    "message": "Authentication Success",
    "access": {
      "token": "4e78daef-c308-4d13-9e18-ab4c80b08a55",
      "expires": 3600
    },
    "refresh": {
      "token": "741138cf-9aac-4a76-baa2-b568b98b8880",
      "expires": 2592000
    }
  }
}";
```

Created a Class with the following:

```
class SiliconAuth
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public network network { get; set; }
    public request request { get; set; }
    public data data { get; set; }
    public refresh refresh { get; set; }
}

public class network
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class request
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class data
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public access access { get; set; }
}

public class access
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int expire { get; set; }
}

public class refresh
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int expire { get; set; }
}
```

And running the following expecting data objects from data:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiliconAuth>(jsonS);
```

But am returning a null value, any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Its difficult to read with that formatting but it looks like refresh is a property of data

Comment: @Crowcoder Fixed the formatting

Comment: Not directly related to the question but very useful if you are doing desalinization of jsons there is a VS build in tool that will generate you classes from json itself its a bit hidden in an extension refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065030/paste-special-json-to-a-class-missing-vs2019-with-all-web-dev-tools-installe)

Comment: There are some tools which help to generate C# classes from json. For example https://json2csharp.com/ or https://app.quicktype.io/.

Answer (score 2):

You are have some typos in your JSON or your class properties. In the JSON you use: `expire` and in the class: `expires`.

You should either change your JSON, or your class properties.

**EDIT** 
Thanks for @Rafal to point this out: 
You should make sure, that your JSON-Structure and your class sturcture is the same. For example you have `refresh` property int the JSON as child of `data`, but in your class its a property of `SiliconAuth`.

Comment: also refresh should be inside data class instead of SiliconAuth

Comment: Thats true. I will add it

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong root class, refesh should be inside of data, no in the root

```
  public class SiliconAuth
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public Network network { get; set; }
        public Request request { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

another classess

```
 public class Network
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Access
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public int expires { get; set; }
    }

    public class Refresh
    {
        public string token { get; set; }
        public int expires { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Access access { get; set; }
        public Refresh refresh { get; set; }
    }
```