# RestSharp API test running endlessly despite getting desired response - what am I missing out?

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization

RestSharp beginner here; I browsed quite a bit but couldn't find the answers (or the ones I found didn't work out). I am trying to find out what I'm missing in my following test that's checking API response for a weather page.

Response code and content values are OK when I check using debugger but I can't figure out why test is running endlessly - apparently I am missing some important part. Added some Console.WriteLines that never get executed due to endless test.

Another issue is that I can't deserialize JSON file to custom created class (created by paste special in VS to avoid any more human made mistakes). Attaching code and example of JSON output below.

```
    public async Task GetWeatherData()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Get);
        RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        if (response.IsSuccessful == true)
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");

        var output = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        WeatherData responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherData>(output);
    }
```

example of API output:

```
{"coord":{"lon":13.7329,"lat":46.1828},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":298.23,"feels_like":298.13,"temp_min":296.13,"temp_max":301.58,"pressure":1008,"humidity":51},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.71,"deg":223,"gust":2.23},"clouds":{"all":62},"dt":1653043444,"sys":{"type":2,"id":19828,"country":"SI","sunrise":1653017233,"sunset":1653071774},"timezone":7200,"id":3189038,"name":"Tolmin","cod":200}
```

Custom made class WeatherData (here also unsure if everything should be under one master class or is it fine like this):

```
public class WeatherData
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Weather[] weather { get; set; }
    public string _base { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public int visibility { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public int timezone { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public float temp { get; set; }
    public float feels_like { get; set; }
    public float temp_min { get; set; }
    public float temp_max { get; set; }
    public int pressure { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public float speed { get; set; }
    public int deg { get; set; }
    public float gust { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public int type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Regarding one facet of your question, did you try copying the JSON output to your clipboard and then using 'Paste Special' to convert it to C# class models? That might make the explicit deserialization easier for you.  More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073028/4516065)

Comment: Regarding the "Test", we'd need more info on how RestSharp is initalized, which test runner you're using, and why you'd need to call the API in a test in the first place.