# How to call VS command to paste Json as C# from code?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, codegen

There is a very useful command in Visual Studio, which permits to paste json from clipboard to C# classes.

Is there a way to use this function (through automation, library or any other way) from our code ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: From the menu; Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste special (json to a class) missing VS2019 - with all web dev tools installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065030/paste-special-json-to-a-class-missing-vs2019-with-all-web-dev-tools-installe)

Comment: @quaabaam actually my question was not about how to use this function in VS, as I already use it. I would like to be able to call it by code. Like I think VS might be automatable or use assembly callable by someone else)