# Missing button Paste Special in VS2022 v17.5.3

Tags: c#, json, .net, visual-studio-2022

I've recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.5.3 and noticed that the "Paste Special" button seems to be missing from the toolbar. This option was really useful for me in the previous version, and I'm wondering if there's any way to get it back.
[image]

I've tried customizing the toolbar and looking for the option in the menus, but can't seem to find it.
Does anyone know if the feature has been removed or if there's a way to bring it back? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste special (json to a class) missing VS2019 - with all web dev tools installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56065030/paste-special-json-to-a-class-missing-vs2019-with-all-web-dev-tools-installe)

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: I am using VS 22(V 17.3.4) two major versions lesser than you, but I have "Paste special" option available on my edit menu.

Comment: I've checked on version 17.3.6, button exists.

Comment: I'm using 17.6.0 Preview 1 and the paste special item is present as well.  There is a note on the [documentation for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) that says "If you don't see the Paste Special option on the Edit menu, make sure that you select the program file for your app. For example, for a C# app, select the Program.cs file in Solution Explorer." It's hard to tell from your screenshot, but are you currently selected on something like a folder in solution explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to All!

Issue fixed using this way/workaround, I added "New Menu" item in Customizing window and added the necessary commands.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Paste Special` option is added by the [Tweaks 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.Tweaks2022) extension.

As with many of Mads' extensions, this functionality has made its way in to Visual Studio itself now.

Comment: issue still exists after install the extension, Visual Studio 2022 v17.5.3 :(

Comment: The `Paste Special` option only works on C# source files I think. It's also possible that other extensions you are using may conflict with it.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use it on C# source.

Comment: I have the Paste Special option available with VS 17.5.3. I don't have that extension installed.